# Пропадает клавиатура в Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

После отправки команды `/start` у меня появляется клавиатура с одной кнопкой `send`. Я хочу чтобы после команды старт пользователь мог вписать какое нибудь слово и отправить это сообщение через мою кнопку и затем уже мне надо словить что пользователь ввел, и что это было сделано с помощью моей кнопки.
Можно ли так сделать?